# Node HTTP request using a named pipe

Tags: node.js, sockets, azure, named-pipes, iisnode

I am trying to request a GET through an existing named pipe. This is to work around the fact that Node processes on Azure are wrapped by IISNode, thus not having a port of their own, but rather being given a named pipe (as the `PORT` environment variable). Node's `net.Server` class knows how to handle named pipes, which explains why HTTP routing works fine (as `http`.Server` seems to use the [same interface](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server)). From the docs:

[Class: net.Server](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_server)  on **`server.listen(path[, callback])`**

> On Windows, the local domain is implemented using a named pipe. The
>   path must refer to an entry in \?\pipe\ or \.\pipe. Any characters
>   are permitted, but the latter may do some processing of pipe names,
>   such as resolving .. sequences. Despite appearances, the pipe name
>   space is flat. Pipes will not persist, they are removed when the last
>   reference to them is closed. Do not forget JavaScript string escaping
>   requires paths to be specified with double-backslashes, such as:

But this is on the receiving/listening end. What I would like to do is to re-use this existing named-pipe to send requests to the listening server, bypassing the external complications of IISNode. *Is this even possible?* (The `named-pipes` package does not seem to apply here, as it seems to provide a too high-level interface that does not resemble the low-level socket/EventEmitter nature I am looking for). There are [indications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750041/how-to-create-a-named-pipe-in-node-js) that it *might* not be possible, but that seems to concern explicitly creating named pipes, not reusing existing ones, which is what I want to do. And it does not say *will not work*, only that it is not *supported*.

I tried doing this to send a request, but I am failing to get a response. It simply hangs doing nothing.

```
var namedPipeLocalDomain= app.config.port;

var options = {
    hostname: namedPipeLocalDomain,
    path: util.format('/api/%s', restPayloadObject.servicepath),
    method: 'GET'
};

logger.info('Creating connection using named pipe, ', namedPipeLocalDomain);

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    logger.info('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    logger.info('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));

    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += data
        logger.info('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log('No more data in response.')
        console.log(body);
    })
});
```

Some .NET guys I talked were of the impression that this won't work as they *thought* (not definitive info) a named pipe only accepts one client reading/writing to the pipe.

Related: [Calling localhost urls on Azure's IISNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089640/calling-localhost-urls-on-azures-iisnode)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using process.env.PORT instead of app.config.port and see if it works. If it does not, the only option is to use Azure VM.